# How to get a list element in rethinkdb document

Tags: arrays, rethinkdb

How to get an element of a list at specified index from a rethinkdb document using RQL?

```
r.db('test').table('user').insert({id: 1, list: ['a','b','c']})
r.db('test').table('user').get(1).do(r.row('list')(0))  // I want to return 'a'
```

Error:

```
RqlRuntimeError: Cannot perform get_field on a non-object non-sequence `"a"`. in:
r.db("test").table("user").get(1).do(function(var_18) { return r.row("list")(0); })
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/#nth

```
r.db('test').table('user').get(1).do(r.row('list').nth(0)) // returns "a"
```

Comment: An even more concise syntax is `r.table("user")("list").nth(0)` no need to break out the `do` when you only want to reference the expression once.

Answer (score 2):

A shorter way to do it is with

```
r.db('test').table('user').get(1)('list').nth(0)
```